# How to convert from type Dbnull to type Date

Tags: vb.net, date, dbnull

```
If IsDBNull(dgv_datapasien.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value.ToString) Then
                    tglcetak = dgv_datapasien.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value.ToString
                    With dgv_datapasien.Rows(iRowIndex)
                        cmdData.CommandText = "Update tabelpasien set no_lab ='" + .Cells(1).Value.ToString + "', no_rm ='" + .Cells(2).Value.ToString + "'
                                        , nama ='" + .Cells(3).Value.ToString + "',jeniskelamin ='" + .Cells(5).Value.ToString + "'
                                       , status ='" + .Cells(6).Value.ToString + "', tglmasuk ='" & FormatTglUniversal(.Cells(8).Value) & "'
                                       , ruangasal ='" + .Cells(7).Value.ToString + "' ,dokterpengirim='" + .Cells(9).Value.ToString + "'
                                       ,analis='" + .Cells(10).Value.ToString + "',umur ='" + .Cells(4).Value.ToString + "',analyzer='" + .Cells(0).Value.ToString + "'

                                        where no_lab ='" + .Cells(1).Value.ToString + "'"
                        ' ,tglcetak='" & FormatDateNull(.Cells(11).Value) & "'
                    End With
                            cmdData.ExecuteNonQuery()

                        End If
```

I need to update database from datagridview by clicking button Update.
One of the field is about datePrint.
But, sometimes, my dateprint is dbnull.
so I have problem to update database because datePrint is dbnull.
my code always show "Conversion from type 'DbNull' to 'Date' type is not valid"
fyi: I use postgresql
Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Show the SQL with the update statement, and include details on the type of database.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing this completely wrong.  Show us the code you have but I suspect that you are looping through the rows of the grid and trying to save each one individually.  What you should be doing is binding a `DataTable` to the grid and using a data adapter to save the changes from the `DataTable` to the database.  In that case, you never touch the data directly.

Comment: To answer the question you actually asked, you don't.  If a grid cell contains a `DbNull` then that represents no value, so that's what you should be saving to the database.

Comment: i've edit to answer your question, thank you @AndrewMortimer

Comment: Have a look at using database parameters. Also, everything that @jmcilhinney said.

Comment: the data in datagridview is not binding from datatable, because not all column from database I call into datagrid. @jmcilhinney

Comment: *not all column from database I call into datagrid"*. That is completely irrelevant. That is, in no way, a reason not to bind a `DataTable` to a `DataGridView` and use a data adapter to retrieve and save data.

Comment: yes, i mean not all column @jmcilhinney

Comment: I know what you mean and it's irrelevant.  What you mean is not a reason not to do what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the datePrint cell during building the SQL query and set the respective  column (in your case `tglcetak`) to NULL if the source value is null, otherwise set it to the date value.

Assuming your source grid cell(11) contains the datePrint value:

```
With dgv_datapasien.Rows(iRowIndex)
    cmdData.CommandText = "Update tabelpasien set no_lab ='" + .Cells(1).Value.ToString + 
                          "', no_rm ='" + .Cells(2).Value.ToString +
                          "', nama ='"  + .Cells(3).Value.ToString +
                          "', jeniskelamin ='" + .Cells(5).Value.ToString + 
                          "', status ='" + .Cells(6).Value.ToString +
                          "', tglmasuk ='" & FormatTglUniversal(.Cells(8).Value) & 
                          "', ruangasal ='" + .Cells(7).Value.ToString +
                          "', dokterpengirim='" + .Cells(9).Value.ToString + 
                          "', analis='" + .Cells(10).Value.ToString + 
                          "', umur ='" + .Cells(4).Value.ToString + 
                          "', analyzer='" + .Cells(0).Value.ToString + "'"

    If IsDBNull(.Cells(11).Value) Then
        cmdData.CommandText &= ",tglcetak=NULL"
    Else
        cmdData.CommandText &= ",tglcetak='" & FormatTglUniversal(.Cells(11).Value) & "'"
    End If

    cmdData.CommandText &= " where no_lab ='" + .Cells(1).Value.ToString + "'"
End With

cmdData.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I don't know what your `FormatDateNull` function returns, so I don't use it above. And I assume your function `FormatTglUniversal` formats the date string to postgresql date format.

I would recommend you get used to using parameterized query for security and performance since your code here is inside a loop.

Comment: I mean, formatDateNull to return string empty if the date is null @ajakblackgoat

Comment: may you like to explain or give me sample about this your suggestion? "I would recommend you get used to using parameterized query for security and performance since your code here is inside a loop."    ------ @ajakblackgoat

Answer (score -1):

Make sure Date Field in database allows null

while passing the parameter to database use below format

input parameter of database = **(dateprint == DBNull.value ? null : (DateTime?)convert.toDateTime(dateprint))**

Comment: use ternary operator it will work in your case shown in above answer

Comment: would you like to explain it more @Amol ?

Comment: use below line **If Not dgv_datapasien.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value Is DBNull.Value Then**

Comment: hi @amol. I'm sorry to late to response. it doesn't work too.